# page background image to cover page cannot get it to work

Tags: html, css

I have this image:

[image]

That I am trying to stretch the height of the page and then repeat horizontally. The repeat horizontally is working fine but it's not covering the page vertically.

I've tried several examples from SO but I'm not getting the results that I want.

Here is where I ended up from another post but now it's not showing at all:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-image: url(bg-4a-24516.png);
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    </style>

    </head>

    <body>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </body>

</html>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/6syJM/

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your example works correctly as you coded it.

The background image is being stretched and may be hard to discern depending on your browser color rendering.

Look at the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/yS4Uz

I have taken the original image and added a colored border to the top and bottom.

You can see the image at:  http://postimage.org/image/fsv80qegn/

When you use the CSS3 property `background-size: cover`, the background image gets stretch and this can lead to some distortion in rendering especially for a gradient.

```
body {
    background-image: url(http://s15.postimage.org/kriqf9i9n/sx_U5g.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

If you change `cover` to `contain` you will get another effect that may be more suitable in other applications.